# App dialog theme shows default title even when windowNoTitle is True

Tags: android

i am working on app showing Layout as An alert dialog in main activity.But,when i created this alert in activity.it always showing title,which is damaging my view.i tried to remove label from  then it is showing title as `in.inspiringwave.firstapp`

Manifest FIle

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.inspiringwave.firstapp">

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Sign In"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan|adjustResize">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FingerprintActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppDialogTheme" />


</application>
```

and app Dialog theme is

```
<style name="AppDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

[output is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASfN0.png)

My requirement is to show alert withOut title 
i have tried all possiblities..still it shows like this[in activity i wrote like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upGbu.jpg)

Fingerprint Activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_fingerprint"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#263237"
tools:context=".FingerprintActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_fingerprint" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/title_fingerprint"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingEnd="30dp"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:text="@string/desc_fingerprint"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingEnd="30dp"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove android: from your style and try like: <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

Comment: Still it shows the same sir

Comment: Are you extending AppCompatActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: i have already tried this too.but not worked

Comment: dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); @manojgundapaneni